# QRCodes Explained?

Tags: barcode, qr-code

Anyone know's any good **documentation** (theorical) about QRCodes?

Answer (score 2):

The QR Code specification is completely explained by [ISO/IEC 18004:2006](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=43655). The bad news is the specification's text is not free. But it is the only complete resource explaining the format.

If that's not what you have in mind, you'll need to explain more about what you are interested in.

Comment: bought a copy, worth every euro

Answer (score 0):

The best open source description I've seen is http://www.swetake.com/qr/qr1_en.html.